# gloud os-login iap in private vm and permissions - ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iap

I created a VM in GCP with oslogin enabled.
The instance uses a service-Account.

I can connect to the instance via `gcloud beta compute ssh ... --tunnel-through-iap`
command as IAM user.
I can also connect with the same command as service account user who has 'rols/owner' permission.
However when I try to connect as with a service account who has the following two permissions

- "roles/compute.osLogin"
- "roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor"
  I get an ERROR:

> ```
> sa_xxxxxxxxxxxxx@compute.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: Permission denied (publickey).
> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
> ```

When I add a role "roles/owner" the connect works.
Of course I want minimal permissions...

What do I wrong? Which permission is missing?

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: can you try to add instanceAdmin V1 role? If it works, try to create a new custom role with the permission `compute.projects.setCommonInstanceMetadata` because the gcloud compute ssh command try to add your ssh key to the instance and need to update the metadata. If it works, I will post it as answer.

Comment: According to
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#gcloud_1
I added the roles:
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor
roles/compute.osLogin

to the service account. It is important also to add
roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1 alone did not help.
Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

To log in to a VM instance that uses a service account, you also need the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role`, see [Configuring OS Login roles on user accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#grant-iam-roles).